# Is it a modal or main verb?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

> I don't need to do the work

Here,  we can see that *need* is the main verb of this sentence.
But when I turn it to a passive then *need* works  like a modal and *do* has became main verb.

> The work doesn't need to be done by me

Why???

Answer (score 1):

It's the same, the main verb doesn't change, only changes its conjugation and the verb complement. There's no modal verb in any sentence, too.

- I **don't need to do** the work.
- The work **doesn't need to be done** by.

In both sentences "*need*" is the main verb. "*Don't and doesn't*" only are auxiliary verbs which they form the negative sentence. "*to do*" and "*to be done*" are verb complements.